# Почему не работает метод сравнения uid?

Tags: java, android, firebase, realm-database

Метод

```
@Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        ///получить uid///
        ZayavkaRef.addValueEventListener(
                new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                        //Get map of users in datasnapshot

                        // Result will be holded Here
                        for (DataSnapshot dsp : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                            Log.d("Irk", dsp.getValue(OtvetShop.class).getUidClient());
                            if (mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid().equals(dsp.getValue(OtvetShop.class).getUidClient())) {
                                isHaveAnswer += 1;

                            }
                        }

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                        // Getting Post failed, log a message
                        Log.w("Arthur", databaseError.toException());
                    }
                });
        ///  Log.d("Arthur", mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid());
        ///  Log.d("joker", String.valueOf(isHaveAnswer));
if (isHaveAnswer >0) {
            FirebaseRecyclerOptions<OtvetShop> options = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<OtvetShop>()
                    .setQuery(ZayavkaRef, OtvetShop.class).build();
            FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<OtvetShop, OtvetShopHolder> adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<OtvetShop, OtvetShopHolder>(options) {
                @Override
                protected void onBindViewHolder(@androidx.annotation.NonNull OtvetShopHolder holder, int position, @androidx.annotation.NonNull OtvetShop model) {


                    Log.d("Arthur", model.getUidClient() + "model");

                    Log.d("Arthur", holder.text_tovar_name.getText().toString());
                    if (mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid().equals(model.getUidClient())) {
                        holder.text_tovar_name.setText(model.getTovarname());
                        holder.text_tovar_price.setText(model.getTovarprice());
                        holder.text_shop_adress.setText(model.getMagazadress());
                        Picasso.get().load(model.getImage()).into(holder.image_tovar_shop);
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public OtvetShopHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
                    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_customer_shop, parent, false);
                    OtvetShopHolder holder = new OtvetShopHolder(view);


                    return holder;
                }
            };
            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
            adapter.startListening();

        }else {
            pusto.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            text_text.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }
}
```

Инициализая

```
ZayavkaRef= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("zayavli");
mAuth=FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
int isHaveAnswer = 0;
```

Else срабатывает. А если убрать if появляется все что есть в бд а мне надо чтобы появлялось только то где прописано uid пользователя который принимает.

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%85%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5

Answer (score 2):

Суть проблемы - непонимание многопоточности. Вы инкрементите переменную `isHaveAnswer` в колбеке, который сработает когда-нибудь потом, а проверяете её значение уже сейчас.
Весь блок `if (isHaveAnswer >0) {...}` нужно перенести в тело колбека следом за циклом.